# Using boolean to detect lower cases. Outcome always true.

Tags: java, boolean

Im trying to create a code to read a password, if the password contains lowercases, boolean should be false and continue with the rest of the code. This is a fragment of the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a password that meets the following rules: \n\n");
    System.out.print("8 characteres long\n");
    System.out.print("Contains at least 1 lower letter\n");
    System.out.print("Contains at least 1 upper letter\n");
    System.out.print("Contains at least 1 numeric digit\n");
    System.out.print("Contains 1 special character from "
    + "the set: !@#$%^&*\n");
    System.out.print("Does not contain the word \"and\" "
    + "or the word \"end\"\n\n");
    String password = stdIn.nextLine();

    boolean hasLower;
    hasLower = true;
    for(int i = 0; (i<password.length()) && (!hasLower); i++){
          if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))){
                hasLower = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hasLower);
    } //end main
} // end class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're logic in the for loop is incorrect.

Since you initialise the `hasLower` variable to true, the condition in the for loop will never be true, so therefore the for loop will never run:

```
(i<password.length()) && (!hasLower) 
// !hasLower will not be true since the variable is initialised to true, whereas it should be initialised to false.
```

So to fix the code, initialise the `hasLower` variable to false and then break from the loop when you find a lowercase character.

```
hasLower = false;
for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
      if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))){
            hasLower = true;
            break; // Exits the last-entered loop.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying this and it gives me the opposite: when I input all capital letters output is false, and when I input lowercase output is true. I am trying to obtain the opposite. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Disregard, I changed true for false and that did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Elrascabuches That's ok! Please mark the answer as accepted so people know the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

As per your logic it will skip the for loop. Pls change the second && operator as (hasLower). Note: These brackets are not needed.

You may have something as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < password.length() && hasLower; i++) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
            hasLower = false;
        }
    }
```